# An Xaml Error: The property "Value" was not found in type "WindowsUIXamlBindingWrapper"

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm coding a Windows 8.1 app that use Hub control.
this project also use *mvvmLight*.

DataContext Class like this

```
public class UserInfoViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    public UserInfo User
    {
        get { return userInfo; }
        set
        {
            if (value == userInfo)
                return;
            userInfo = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("User");
        }
    }
    public UserInfoViewModel()
    {


        User = new UserInfo()
        {
            NikeName = "User",
            ProfileImage = "ms-appx:///image/test.jpg"
        };

    }
}
```

When I use `HubSection.ContentTemplate` like this,
**it's seems something wrong with the binding**

```
  <HubSection.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <StackPanel
                                    DataContext="{Binding User, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection.ContentTemplate>
```

There will have an XAML error

> The property "Value" was not found in type "WindowsUIXamlBindingWrapper"

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Remove(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.WindowsRuntimeContext.UnregisterDynamicType(Type dynamicType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.UnregisterDynamicType(Type dynamicType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.Reset()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlProjectMetadata.OnTypesInvalidatedInternal(IList`1 invalidatedAssemblies)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.TypeResolver.OnAssemblyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlProjectMetadata.OnAssemblyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectAssemblyCollection.FireChangedEvent(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectAssemblyCollection.AssemblyCollection_EnumerationChanged(Object sender, EnumerationChangedEventArgs`1 e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Collections.NotifyingCollectionBase`1.EventInvoker(EnumerationChangedEventArgs`1 eventArguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Events.SuspendingEventManager`1.ForwardEvents()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Events.Suspender.SuspendDisposer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Events.Suspender.SuspendDisposer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Assemblies.AssemblyCollection.AssemblyService_AssembliesUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs`1 e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Assemblies.AssemblyService.OnAssembliesUpdated(IEnumerable`1 assemblyInformation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Assemblies.AssemblyService.RefreshDesignerCaches()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.SetIterationContext(String[] paths)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.SynchronizeDesignerContext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.ProcessShadowCopyResults(IEnumerable`1 results)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Assemblies.AssemblyService.FlushShadowCopyUpdateQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.DesignerProcess.RunApplication()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.DesignerProcess.DesignProcessViewProvider.AppContainerDesignerProcessRun(String[] activationContextArgs)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.DesignerProcess.DesignProcessViewProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<applicationView_Activated>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: you need to add sample code for the datacontext part.

Comment: thanks for your help,actually I wonder  the HubSection's ContentTemplate  DataTemplate can't right show  in design tools when use DataContext.